# 7Zip hangs when executing from SSIS

Tags: ssis, 7zip

I am calling a batch file from SSIS which includes the line:

```
7z x -o%1  %1 -r
```

to extract all text files from a large number of .gz archives distributed through 24 different folder, placing the extracted files into the base folder. There are appx 5000 .gz archives, each containing only one text file.

This batch runs fine when called from the command line, but when executed from a SSIS package in debug mode, it unzips about 30 files then stalls. When I quit the SSIS debugger, the unzipping continues and the batch file finishes. Any idea why the unzipping would stall as long as the SSIS debug window is open?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you use the `-bb3` switch to turn on verbose logging, and see if the logs give you any clue, or at least give you a consistent file that it gets stuck on. Does it get stuck on the same file?

Comment: Okay, the log showed no errors and apparently I was filling the buffer with all of the output of unzipping 5000 archives. Once I added >nul when calling the batch file, everything worked fine (and faster). Thank you for responding so quickly!

Comment: I’m pleased you found the issue. You should be able to post as an answer and accept.